# ASP Net Core Dependency Injection - dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, idisposable

According to Microsofts documentation, the `IOC Container` is repsonsible for cleanup of types it creates and calls Dispose on `IDisposable` Interfaces
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#:~:text=Disposal%20of%20services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#:%7E:text=Disposal%20of%20services)
-> so will the container also call Dispose on `IDisposable` Interfaces when they are generated in the `context` of an injected object?

e.g.:
in startup.cs:

```
services.AddhttpClient<CustomClient>(c => {
c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Endpoint"]);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));});
```

in this case, CustomClient will be disposed by the IOC Container, dispose is not needed to be called by developer.

in CustomClient:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"api/users/{email}");
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await  
httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`HttpResponseMessage` implements `IDisposable`, Do i need to use `using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);`
so dispose will be called or is this resource also disposed by the container?

Comment: No. The DI container only disposes objects it creates/manages. Since the `HttpRequestMessage` is being newed up in your class, the DI container knows nothing about it and won't dispose it.

Comment: If you register anything within `services` and it implements `IDisposable`, the `Dispose()` method will be called when the scope,within the object was being created will also be disposed. If you have within your class disposable resources, you have to call their `Dispose()` method when appropiate (either by using `using` statement or within your own `Dispose()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this resource also disposed by the container?

The container only disposes instances which are registered with the provider and which the provider is used to create. In this case, `HttpResponseMessage` is created by `HttpClient`, and should be disposed by your code.

Comment: Hi Stephen, as an aside do you know any tool to show unmanaged/disposable objects not wrapped in a `using` (or explicitly being disposed)?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Re# is pretty good at that. No tool is 100%, though.